# from one array find items in another array

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two arrays. The elements are identical, but the values can be different. 
The two elements i need to see if they match are .fromSourceId and .toSourceId

The two arrays that i am comparing are userCompareData and userData. The number of elements will change. Ultimately, i am seeing if userComparedata is matched in userData if it is not there then add to createChange

So, if userCompareData.toSourceId = userData.toSourceId and userCompareData.fromSourceId = userData.fromSourceId i need to not add the matching userCompareData to the createChange method.

```
addPermissionsForCopy = function(){

    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.userData.length; i++) {
        isFound = false;
        for (var j = 0; j < $scope.userCompareData.length; j++) {

            if ($scope.userCompareData[j].fromSourceID === $scope.userData[i].fromSourceID) {
                if ($scope.userCompareData[j].toSourceID === $scope.userData[i].toSourceID) {
                    isFound = true;
                }
            }
        }

        if (isFound === false) {
            $scope.createChange($scope.userCompareData[i].fromSourceID, $scope.userCompareData[i].toSourceID, true, $scope.selectedUserName);
        }
    }
};
```

This isn't quite right as the number of elements in the data will be different every time this method is called. userData may contain 6 items and then the next 2 same with userCompareData.

Comment: why don't you just hold userCompareData index instead of this boolean? remember you can get out of a `for` using `break`

Comment: Im not sure what you mean or how to do that

Comment: in this example user data can contain 6 items and compare might be 2

Comment: @piddler he means that after you found _it_, you can stop iterating. Imagine you found it within 1-3 iterations out of 1000, it makes sense to stop, i.e. `break` out of a loop (inside of your if statements)

Comment: argh, using `break` alone doesn't solve this issue... it's better invert this loops

Comment: Yes bro ..userComVal and userDataVal both are objects.. so to compare value use .. userComVal .thatproperty and userDataVal .someProperty.. try this..this should help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Invert these loops so you can hold an index which hasn't found:

```
addPermissionsForCopy = function(){

    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.userCompareData.length; i++) {
        isFound = false;
        for (var j = 0; j < $scope.userData.length; j++) {

            if ($scope.userCompareData[i].fromSourceID === $scope.userData[j].fromSourceID) {
                if ($scope.userCompareData[i].toSourceID === $scope.userData[j].toSourceID) {
                    isFound = true;
                }
            }
        }

        if (isFound === false) {
            $scope.createChange($scope.userCompareData[i].fromSourceID, $scope.userCompareData[i].toSourceID, true, $scope.selectedUserName);
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: what if userComparedata has 6 elements and userData only 2. This will untimately keep adding the two elements if they dont match on every userCompareData iteration.

Comment: So? It’s what you want, isn’t? If no userData has matched to compareUserData then compareUserData is added into createChange

Answer (score 0):

```
Try angular.forEach():
var isFound=false;
angular.forEach(userCompareData, function(userComVal){
   angular.forEach(userData, function(userDataVal){
      if(userComval==userDataVal){
        //do what you want on true
        isFound=true;
      }else{
          isFound=false;
      }
   });
   if(isFound==false){
    //do what you want
    $scope.createChange($scope.userCompareData[i].fromSourceID, $scope.userCompareData[i].toSourceID, true, $scope.selectedUserName);
  }
});
```

Comment: Im only trying to match tosource and from sourceid there are other elements i dont want to compare.

Comment: angular.forEach() does every comparison for you.. just it will compare every value ..

Comment: I only need to compare toSource and from source from one array to tosource and fromSource in the other array. There will be other elements i dont want to match.